# Delete a list of files from SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, windows, filesystems, command-prompt

I have a SQL Server table with a list of file paths for files that I need to delete from my windows system, is there any way I can accomplish this using batch file in command prompt or any software to help me do this?? appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a select statement that will create the commands for you, then run it from the command line:

e.g.

```
SELECT 'del /Q ' + file_name FROM your_table;
```

Save the output results to a file, then you can run it from the command line.

Comment: Isn't the standard Windows command to delete files called `DEL` (or `ERASE`; but not `DELETE`) ??

Answer (score 0):

And you may automate the whole thing a little bit more by doing it on the command line with sqlcmd:

```
sqlcmd -d MyDb -Q "SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'DELETE /Q ' + file_name AS x FROM your_table UNION ALL SELECT 'EXIT') AS x" -h -1 -o temp.bat
temp.bat
DEL temp.bat
```

Comment: A virus disguised as `sqlcmd`, how nasty! (It should be `DEL` or `ERASE` instead of `DELETE`, by the way.)